# How to write change values of elements in an array using if else statement and write them to excel?

Tags: java, arrays, excel, if-statement, apache-poi

I have written a code in java where the array has two elements,their values changes by if else statement.The console shows right answer.But in the excel sheet the values for both the elements are zero.
Is there anything that I am missing in the code?

```html
 int StartState=0;
           int EndState=0;
         
          Object[][] TransProbArray = {
                     {StartState,EndState},
                     
             };
          
      
      StartState=1;
      if(StartState==1) {
       EndState=2;
      }else {
       EndState=4;
      }
      
      System.out.println(EndState);
     
      StartState=2;
      if(StartState==2) {
         EndState=4;
       }else{ 
         EndState=5;
       }
        System.out.println(EndState);
          
           
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
             for (Object[] TPA : TransProbArray) {
            
            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
            int columnCount = 0;
             
            for (Object field : TPA) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount++);
                if (field instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }else  if (field instanceof Double) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Double) field);
            }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is nothing to do with Excel, it's down to the identity of the objects you are creating. When you initialise your TransProbArray, you set it's 2 Object members to be the Integers StartState and EndState. At the point of initialisation, these are both equal to zero. However Integers are immutable, and once you assign them to new values (StartState = 1 for example), you are not changing the values of the original objects in the array (which remain as zero), but creating new Integer objects. Therefore at the end of your code the objects in your TPA array no longer reference the same objects as StartState and EndState, they contain the original zero values as at initialisation.

To fix this, you could update the values of your array after the values of StartState and EndState have been changed, e.g.

```
StartState=1;
if (StartState==1) {
      EndState=2;
} else {
      EndState=4;
}
TransProbArray[0][0] = StartState;
TransProbArray[0][1] = EndState;
```